# How to change the URL without change the page in php?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I have this URL when I click on a link that redirect me in '`domaine.php/subject1`' :

```
www.mywebsite.com/domaine.php/subject1
```

I want to display an URL like this when I want to see an other subject:

```
www.mywebsite.com/domaine.php/subject2
```

But when I click on the link 'domaine.php/subject2' in the same page (page:domaine.php), it display:

```
www.mywebsite.com/domaine.php/domaine.php/subject2
```

What can I do to fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add some more details probably the code you written so far so others can help

Comment: Keep in mind that we cannot look over your shoulder, we do not see the code you are using. You need to post the relevant sections of your code here for us to be able to help. Specifically how the link looks like and what rewriting rules you have implemented.

Comment: Add a "/" before your relative links, e.g. `'/domaine.php/subject2'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Absolute vs relative URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls)

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information, next time I will be careful. Thanks to rndus2r, it was simple as add a  "/" before my link. Problem solve.